# Flutter - How to place the buttons like this layout?

Tags: flutter, button, grid

I want to place the buttons like the below image. Someone please help me to do the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving that design.

You can simply use `Row` with `Column` on the side and a `GridView`in the middle.

Or

You can also use `Row` with `3 Columns` and in the middle `Column` you again insert a `Row`.

Here is an example with Column and Gridview

```
Row(children: [
  Column(
    children: List.generate(7, (index) => button1()),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemCount: 9,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => button2()),
  ),
  Column(
    children: List.generate(7, (index) => button1()),
  ),
]);
```

Here `button1` and `button2` will be your respective buttons. This will generate the required layout. You can modify the code according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below link and found the solution.

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/@lets4r/flutorial-create-a-staggered-gridview-9c881a9b0b98)